# Help Importing account into GETH using UTC Keystore File

Tags: go-ethereum

After having installed GETH using Homebrew on my Mac I manage to create a account, shortly after I copy my UTC file into the Keystore folder

I ran `eth.accounts` and it showed my new account still.

How do I successfully check my balance? is my account already linked now into GETH?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should be nothing more you need to do. You can check your balance via the console: `web3.eth.getBalance('0x123abc')`, but you'll need `geth` to be up-to-date (sync'd with the blockchain) before that will give you an accurate result.

If you just want to check the balance, https://etherscan.io is an easier way.

Comment: Hi @smarx so I would run web3.eth.getBalance('Account Address') inside of GETH command line which starts with > not the Mac Terminal?

also how do I make sure Geth is synced? it just keeps on running in the background?

Comment: Also I know my balance still I want to make sure I am ready to send a transfer

Comment: Correct. Check to see that recent blocks are around the "last block" at https://etherscan.io/.

Comment: I am not at home right now still say when I check verify my balance how will I be able to send a transaction to another address? also I am connected to the main net already correct so any transactions I do will be final?

Comment: Yes, transactions will be final. You can use `web3.eth.sendTransaction`.